# many integer records or one text field

Tags: mysql

I'm designing a **largescale website**.

for preventing duplicate voting, I'm going to store **user's votes (userid , postid)** in database (im using mysql now)

which one is better? 
1- have just **one row for each user** and store all postid he'd voted as a **text field** there.
2- have **one row for each vote** and store it as **integer**.

thanks

Comment: Depends on your application.  If you are designing a **largescale website**, there are efficiencies you always need to consider, specific to your own use cases.  There's always an answer for a general case, but if thousands to millions of people will be accessing your website every minute, will you be joining multiple tables?  how many users are you expecting? how many polls are you doing?  are you really expecting to go through a long text field? how does caching come into play? etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. The text-based approach has the potential to overflow. You're gonna have to set a maximum size for that text field, and, even then, a high enough number of votes will exceed capacity and cause your code to fail.
2. The text-based approach has the potential to be very slow. Suppose I've voted for 100,000 posts. Checking if I've voted for Post X will involve downloading those 100,000 post IDs, parsing them into an array, and checking the array for Post X's ID. That's gonna be way slower than an indexed query of `SELECT 1 FROM votes WHERE user_id = X and post_id = Y LIMIT 1;`, which will always run at almost exactly the same speed: pretty darn fast if it's indexed. (If not, it'll essentially do the same thing as your text-based approach and be super-slow, so indexing will be very important here!) Plus, note that if you go with MySQL's `LONGTEXT` to avoid issue #1, you stand to transfer up to 4GB of data each time you want to check for a single vote. Eww.

In my experience, your row-per-vote approach will actually be *simpler* to implement (especially once you get comfortable with SQL), will scale better, and will have many fewer ways in which it could break. There are scales at which relational databases become infeasible, but, for almost all users, using SQL to its full potential is the best way to get great performance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is your second option.  Relational databases are good at this stuff.

Make a table called `uservotes` or something, with the primary key of `userid` and `postid`.  That automatically prevents duplicate votes being added.  It also means you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(vote) FROM uservotes WHERE postid=42;
```

Not that you would do that...  You'd probably just store the total vote on the post itself.